# Cannot Execute .sh file during maven build on windows(CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application)

Tags: java, windows, maven, build, sh

I am using windows 10. When I using maven build on the project. During the process will execute .sh file. But the console would output CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application and failure. May I ask how to run .sh file during the maven build on windows? My pom file is as below. I have struggle for days and search for a long time. I use maven 3.3.9

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>testing</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <executable>${basedir}/src/hello-proto.sh</executable>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: how do you expect to run a .sh file on windows?

Comment: Not possible? I think eclipse may have some plugin. Then how do you think the workaround. Is it change the .sh to .bat be the only way? I have use WSL. And I could execute the .sh without any problems. But just don't know how to make it work in eclipse.

Comment: that is not an eclipse issue. Your .sh file probably contains calls to linux binaries which simply don't exist on a windows machine. And an .sh file is not a runnable file on windows, that might be limited to .exe and .bat/.cmd

Comment: my script file just contain the below statement. #!/usr/bin/env bash

git archive --remote ssh://git@vcs.hello.net/test/ 0.0.1 proto | tar x -C ./src/main/  . The problem is if I use maven build in WSL would be no problem. But if I used eclipse, just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: That is a linux script file and cannot be run on windows. There are no binaries for `bash` and `tar`. That script is clearly written for linux, why do you expect it to work on windows?

Comment: ok. I see. Then I find another way. Thx a lot.

Comment: @f1sh there a quite few unix tools available for windoze, but i'd avoid using such tools for a maven build, unless there is a very good reason ...

Comment: Oh. Could u pls recommend some good tools?

Comment: @chanjordan did u find any solution to this problem.I'm facing same issue